# How to stretch plot vertically in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, range, stretch

My x-axis ranges from `-30 to 35`, however my y-axis ranges from `-1 to 1`, so I was wondering how I could make my graph longer without having to multiply the coordinates by a constant.

Here is my code: (plotting lines between circles if parts of data match, where namei and namej are just counters)

```
    fig = plt.figure(0)
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
    ax.set_aspect('equal')
    plt.axis([-30, 35, -1, 1])

    line1 = plt.plot([5, 10],[-0.5, 0], c='k', marker='o')
    line2 = plt.plot([10, 20],[0, 0.75], c='k', marker='o')
    line3 = plt.plot([20, 35],[0.75, 1], c='k', marker='o')
```

Comment: Please follow [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). You are close, but we could really use a minimal data set to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @MartinEvans Hi Martin, thanks for this! I have now edited this for the first three lines of data, hope this helps!

Comment: Have you tried just removing the `set_axpect('equal')` line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should remove the `ax.set_aspect('equal')` line to allow `matplotlib` to stretch the axis to fit.

This would give you the following output:
[image]

As follows:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure(0)
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
#ax.set_aspect('equal')
plt.axis([-30, 35, -1, 1])

line1 = plt.plot([5, 10],[-0.5, 0], c='k', marker='o')
line2 = plt.plot([10, 20],[0, 0.75], c='k', marker='o')
line3 = plt.plot([20, 35],[0.75, 1], c='k', marker='o')

plt.show()
```